# Google Maps API with KML layers, how to add Search Box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I'm making a city zoning map, with kml layers.  I'd like to add a search box, so I can search for addresses.

How would I add [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox), to my map?  I'm still really new to coding, so the simpler explanation, the better!  Though, I'm not a complete moron.

```html
<html>
<head>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


var map;

// lets define some vars to make things easier later
var kml = {
    a: {
        name: "City of Forest Lake",
        url: "http://forestlakezoning.weebly.com/uploads/5/3/5/6/53562351/forest_lake.kmz"
    },
    b: {
        name: "C - Conservation",
        url: "http://forestlakezoning.weebly.com/uploads/5/3/5/6/53562351/c.kmz"
    }
// keep adding more if ye like 
};

// initialize our goo
function initializeMap() {
    var options = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.25, -92.95),
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);

    createTogglers();
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMap);

// the important function... kml[id].xxxxx refers back to the top 
function toggleKML(checked, id) {

    if (checked) {

        var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kml[id].url, {
            preserveViewport: true,
            suppressInfoWindows: true 
        });
        // store kml as obj
        kml[id].obj = layer;
        kml[id].obj.setMap(map);
    }
    else {
        kml[id].obj.setMap(null);
        delete kml[id].obj;
    }

};

// create the controls dynamically because it's easier, really
function createTogglers() {

    var html = "<form><ul>";
    for (var prop in kml) {
        html += "<li id=\"selector-" + prop + "\"><input type='checkbox' id='" + prop + "'" +
        " onclick='highlight(this,\"selector-" + prop + "\"); toggleKML(this.checked, this.id)' \/>" +
        kml[prop].name + "<\/li>";
    }
    html += "<li class='control'><a href='#' onclick='removeAll();return false;'>" +
    "Remove all layers<\/a><\/li>" + 
    "<\/ul><\/form>";

    document.getElementById("toggle_box").innerHTML = html;
};

// easy way to remove all objects
function removeAll() {
    for (var prop in kml) {
        if (kml[prop].obj) {
            kml[prop].obj.setMap(null);
            delete kml[prop].obj;
        }

    }
};


// Append Class on Select
function highlight(box, listitem) {
    var selected = 'selected';
    var normal = 'normal';
    document.getElementById(listitem).className = (box.checked ? selected: normal);
};

function startup() { 
// for example, this toggles kml b on load and updates the menu selector
var checkit = document.getElementById('a');
checkit.checked = true;
toggleKML(checkit, 'a');
highlight(checkit, 'selector1');
 }

</script>



<style type="text/css">
.selected { font-weight: bold; }
}

      #pac-input {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-left: 12px;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 400px;
      }

      #pac-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
      }

      .pac-container {
        font-family: Roboto;
      }

      #type-selector {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
      }

      #type-selector label {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }


</style>

</head>
<body onload="startup()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 600px;"></div>
<div id="toggle_box" style="position: overflow; top: 100px; right: 20px; padding: 10px; background: #fff; z-index: 1; "></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are asking how to add [Geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) to your page that geocodes user input?

Comment: I'm not sure. Basically, you type in an address and a marker pops up. That's what I'm going for.

Comment: You mean like [this example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple)?

Comment: That's it.  I looked at the originally and decided on the Search Box.  Now, I'm reevaluating my choice.

Answer (score 1):

See the [example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple)

```js
var map;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (!!results[0].geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
      } else if (!!results[0].geometry.bounds) {
        map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.bounds);
      } else {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      }
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}


// lets define some vars to make things easier later
var kml = {
  a: {
    name: "City of Forest Lake",
    url: "http://forestlakezoning.weebly.com/uploads/5/3/5/6/53562351/forest_lake.kmz"
  },
  b: {
    name: "C - Conservation",
    url: "http://forestlakezoning.weebly.com/uploads/5/3/5/6/53562351/c.kmz"
  }
  // keep adding more if ye like 
};


// initialize our goo
function initializeMap() {
  var options = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.25, -92.95),
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);

  createTogglers();
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMap);

// the important function... kml[id].xxxxx refers back to the top 
function toggleKML(checked, id) {

  if (checked) {

    var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kml[id].url, {
      preserveViewport: true,
      suppressInfoWindows: true
    });
    // store kml as obj
    kml[id].obj = layer;
    kml[id].obj.setMap(map);
  } else {
    kml[id].obj.setMap(null);
    delete kml[id].obj;
  }

};

// create the controls dynamically because it's easier, really
function createTogglers() {

  var html = "<form><ul>";
  for (var prop in kml) {
    html += "<li id=\"selector-" + prop + "\"><input type='checkbox' id='" + prop + "'" +
      " onclick='highlight(this,\"selector-" + prop + "\"); toggleKML(this.checked, this.id)' \/>" +
      kml[prop].name + "<\/li>";
  }
  html += "<li class='control'><a href='#' onclick='removeAll();return false;'>" +
    "Remove all layers<\/a><\/li>" +
    "<\/ul><\/form>";

  document.getElementById("toggle_box").innerHTML = html;
};

// easy way to remove all objects
function removeAll() {
  for (var prop in kml) {
    if (kml[prop].obj) {
      kml[prop].obj.setMap(null);
      delete kml[prop].obj;
    }

  }
};


// Append Class on Select
function highlight(box, listitem) {
  var selected = 'selected';
  var normal = 'normal';
  document.getElementById(listitem).className = (box.checked ? selected : normal);
};

function startup() {
  // for example, this toggles kml b on load and updates the menu selector
  var checkit = document.getElementById('a');
  checkit.checked = true;
  toggleKML(checkit, 'a');
  highlight(checkit, 'selector1');
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', startup);
```

```css
.selected {
  font-weight: bold;
}
}
#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 400px;
}
#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}
.pac-container {
  font-family: Roboto;
}
#type-selector {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}
#type-selector label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Go!" onclick="codeAddress();" />
<input type="text" id="address" value="Columbus, MN" />
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 600px;"></div>
<div id="toggle_box" style="position: overflow; top: 100px; right: 20px; padding: 10px; background: #fff; z-index: 1; "></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### How to add search box

1 Load [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places), for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
```

> Note: To use the functionality contained within this library, you must
>   first load it using the libraries parameter in the Maps API bootstrap
>   URL: `libraries=places`

2. Create the search box and link it to the UI element.

HTML:

```
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
```

JavaScript:

```
// Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
var input = (document.getElementById(controlId));
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
```

3 Initialize Search Box control:

```
function initSearchBox(map,controlId) {
    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    var input = (document.getElementById(controlId));
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);

    // [START region_getplaces]
    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
    // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
    google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function () {
        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

        if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        //get first place
        var place = places[0];

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            title: place.name,
            position: place.geometry.location
        });

        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);


    });
}
```

**Complete example**

```js
var map;

// lets define some vars to make things easier later
var kml = {
    a: {
        name: "City of Forest Lake",
        url: "http://forestlakezoning.weebly.com/uploads/5/3/5/6/53562351/forest_lake.kmz"
    },
    b: {
        name: "C - Conservation",
        url: "http://forestlakezoning.weebly.com/uploads/5/3/5/6/53562351/c.kmz"
    }
    // keep adding more if ye like 
};

// initialize our goo
function initializeMap() {
    var options = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.25, -92.95),
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);

    createTogglers();

    initSearchBox(map, 'pac-input');
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeMap);


function initSearchBox(map,controlId) {
    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    var input = (document.getElementById(controlId));
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);

    // [START region_getplaces]
    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
    // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
    google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function () {
        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

        if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        //get first place
        var place = places[0];

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            title: place.name,
            position: place.geometry.location
        });

        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);


    });
}


// the important function... kml[id].xxxxx refers back to the top 
function toggleKML(checked, id) {

    if (checked) {

        var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kml[id].url, {
            preserveViewport: true,
            suppressInfoWindows: true
        });
        // store kml as obj
        kml[id].obj = layer;
        kml[id].obj.setMap(map);
    }
    else {
        kml[id].obj.setMap(null);
        delete kml[id].obj;
    }

};

// create the controls dynamically because it's easier, really
function createTogglers() {

    var html = "<form><ul>";
    for (var prop in kml) {
        html += "<li id=\"selector-" + prop + "\"><input type='checkbox' id='" + prop + "'" +
        " onclick='highlight(this,\"selector-" + prop + "\"); toggleKML(this.checked, this.id)' \/>" +
        kml[prop].name + "<\/li>";
    }
    html += "<li class='control'><a href='#' onclick='removeAll();return false;'>" +
    "Remove all layers<\/a><\/li>" +
    "<\/ul><\/form>";

    document.getElementById("toggle_box").innerHTML = html;
};

// easy way to remove all objects
function removeAll() {
    for (var prop in kml) {
        if (kml[prop].obj) {
            kml[prop].obj.setMap(null);
            delete kml[prop].obj;
        }

    }
};


// Append Class on Select
function highlight(box, listitem) {
    var selected = 'selected';
    var normal = 'normal';
    document.getElementById(listitem).className = (box.checked ? selected : normal);
};

function startup() {
    // for example, this toggles kml b on load and updates the menu selector
    var checkit = document.getElementById('a');
    checkit.checked = true;
    toggleKML(checkit, 'a');
    highlight(checkit, 'selector1');
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
    <style>
    .selected {
        font-weight: bold;
    }


    #pac-input {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-left: 12px;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 400px;
    }

        #pac-input:focus {
            border-color: #4d90fe;
        }

    .pac-container {
        font-family: Roboto;
    }

    #type-selector {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
    }

    #type-selector label {
            font-family: Roboto;
            font-size: 13px;
            font-weight: 300;
    }
</style>
<body onload="startup()">
        <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 600px;"></div>
        <div id="toggle_box" style="position: overflow; top: 100px; right: 20px; padding: 10px; background: #fff; z-index: 1; "></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That was really helpful. When I want to add ither functions, like display All kmz layers, do I basically follow the same principle as what you presented here? It might be worth my time to check out jq a little more. This is a jq thing, right?

Comment: This is my current product;  http://forestlakezoning.weebly.com/.  I'd like to add an Add All Layers function and possibly a click to zoom.  Any suggestions?